# OCaml Opam install depext Error

Tags: dependencies

I'm struggling with the depext trying to install it, obviously it's a big fail.

By executing this command

```
opam install depext
```

I get this error

```
[ERROR] Solver failed: "/usr/bin/aspcud
        /home/toto/.opam/log/solver-in-4016-5f1023
        /home/toto/.opam/log/solver-out-4016-58c514
        -count(removed),-sum(request,version-lag),-count(down),-sum(solution,version-lag),-count(changed)"
        exited with code 1 "ERROR: grounder returned with non-zero exit status"
```

I'm actually running this on a ubuntu 19.04 with an OCaml version of 4.05.0. I already installed Opam in order to get the dependencies of Liquidsoap, following this tutorial

```
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-internet-radio-station-icecast-and-liquidsoap
```

I am going to install liquidsoap by using apt package.

Anyway, I am curious about the reasons of the install failure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `aspcud` is doing shit then I decided to use `mccs` as external solver.

configuration details are here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448052/how-to-define-mccs-clingo-as-a-opam-solver-instead-of-aspcud/59459896#59459896